# How can I update the data taken from the api using the updated context data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-context

I have a simple online market; which get data from fake api. There is no "quantity" in this api, when I get the data I add the "quantity" to an array of objects that are passed out of the api and control the cart state based on the context.
Now I want to display the product quantity in the product list when the user clicks the "add to cart" button. But because the data on this page comes from api, I can't updat "quantity".
How can I display updated "quantity" on this page?!
[image]

```
const ProductSlider = () => {
const {cart} = useCart()
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
getProducts()
}, [])

const getProducts = async () => {
try {
  const {data} = await http.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  const newData = data.map((obj) => ({...obj, quantity: 0}))
  setProducts(newData.slice(0, 8))
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
}
return (
<main className={styles.container}>
  <header className={styles.swiperHeader}>
    <h3>Latest Products</h3>
    <button>more</button>
  </header>
  <Swiper
    freeMode={true}
    grabCursor={true}
    modules={[FreeMode]}
    className={styles.mySwiper}
    slidesPerView={4}
    spaceBetween={30}>
    {products.length ? (
      products.map((item) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={item.id}>
          <SingleProduct item={item} />
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))
     ) : (
      <p>Loading</p>
    )}
   </Swiper>
   </main>
   )
   }
```

there is no problem in cart page because data get from context.

```
const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "ADD_TO_CART": {
  const updatedCart = [...state.cart]
  const itemIndex = updatedCart.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
  )
  if (itemIndex < 0) {
    const updatedItem = {...updatedCart[itemIndex]}
    updatedItem.quantity++
    updatedCart[itemIndex] = updatedItem
    updatedCart.push({...action.payload})
    // updatedCart.push({...action.payload, quantity: 1})
  } else {
    const updatedItem = {...updatedCart[itemIndex]}
    updatedItem.quantity++
    updatedCart[itemIndex] = updatedItem
  }
  return {...state, cart: updatedCart}
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by passing "cart" to the CartControl component.
I found the clicked product in the cart and returned the quantity of this product.

```
const CartControl = ({add, remove, item, cart}) => {
const searchInCart = (cart, product) => {
const updatedProduct = cart.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
return updatedProduct.quantity
}
return (
<div className={styles.cartControl}>
  <button onClick={add}>+</button>
  <span>{searchInCart(cart, item)}</span>
  {searchInCart(cart, item) > 1 ? (
    <button className={styles.decQuantity} onClick={remove}>
      -
    </button>
   ) : (
    <button className={styles.red} onClick={remove}>
      <FaTrash />
    </button>
    )}
   </div>
   )
   }

    export default CartControl
```